# How to animate image shape into a trapezium, hopefully using a jquery plugin

Tags: jquery, css, animation, jquery-plugins

I am trying to make an animation that will transform a square image into a 'sideways trapezium'. like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/QRtgz.png (ignore the 0 and 1)

I've been searching like crazy for a simple and light jQuery plugin, but not much is coming up. I would prefer to stick to jquery to make it compatible with as many browsers, but I am open to CSS alternatives?

Thanks in advance

Comment: [SEE THIS](http://sitepop.wordpress.com/2012/09/30/jquery-path-animation-using-simple-shapes/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.skewed {
    transform: perspective(500px) rotateY(45deg);
    -webkit-transform: perspective(500px) rotateY(45deg);
    -moz-transform: perspective(500px) rotateY(45deg);
    -ms-transform: perspective(500px) rotateY(45deg);
    -o-transform: perspective(500px) rotateY(45deg);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/43gLv/

- rotateY rotates the element on the Y axis (vertical axis) N degrees
- perspective makes it render as a 3d perspective with the viewer N pixels away

---

To perform the animation (transition).

```
.skewed {
    transition: all 2s ease;
    -webkit-transition: all 2s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 2s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 2s ease;
    -o-transition: all 2s ease;
}
.skewed:hover {
    transform: perspective(500px) rotateY(45deg);
    -webkit-transform: perspective(500px) rotateY(45deg);
    -moz-transform: perspective(500px) rotateY(45deg);
    -ms-transform: perspective(500px) rotateY(45deg);
    -o-transform: perspective(500px) rotateY(45deg);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/43gLv/2/

**EDIT** To just shrink one edge you use transform-origin

```
transform-origin: left center 0;
-webkit-transform-origin: left center 0;
-moz-transform-origin: left center 0;
-ms-transform-origin: left center 0;
-o-transform-origin: left center 0;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/43gLv/3/

Comment: I've been finding this sort of solution a lot, the only problem is that this is more of a rhombus shape than a trapezium. I'm looking for a way to "shrink" just one edge of the image

Comment: @user1960089 That's why I didn't post this as an answer.  I still can't find something that will shrink one side, though...  Still looking.

Comment: @user1960089 - Just use transform-origin and set the origin to the side you don't want to shrink, check my edit for an example.

Comment: @user1477388 - transform-origin is what your looking for

Comment: @LastCoder I have tried as per http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform-origin.asp but wasn't able to shift just one corner of the div.  If you can produce an example, please do.  Thanks.

Comment: @user1477388 - if you check my last jsfiddle example http://jsfiddle.net/43gLv/3/ I'm sure you can play around with it and figure something out. But using the phrase "shift just one corn" isn't very descriptive, could you mean translate, rotate, scale? You could use transform-origin: left top 0; to hole the top left corner in place.

Comment: Basically, I what I think the OP is asking for is how to rotate a div diagonally.  For instance, if your push back the top left corner of a plane, the bottom right corner of the plane will appear closer and the top left corner will appear further away.  Is that possible in CSS/jQuery?

Comment: @user1477388 - I've already answered that, please read over my previous comment. The JSFiddle example I created animates the transform when you hover over the 2nd image.

Comment: Personally, this isn't what I am talking about so we must have a communication problem; but perhaps, it is what the OP wants, so thanks, anyway.  Maybe I have misunderstood their requirements.

Comment: This is what I was talking about (I posted an answer below).

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are requesting:  Push back top left corner which brings bottom right corner closer.

```
<div class="perspective"><div class="square">the square</div></div>

.perspective{
    -webkit-perspective : 800px
}
.square{
    margin: 20px;
    -webkit-transform-origin: center center;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background:#AAA;
}
.square:hover{
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(-5deg) rotateZ(5deg) rotateY(-5deg);
}
```

Example (hover over the div):

http://jsfiddle.net/ewGWj/17/

Exaggerated example:

http://jsfiddle.net/ewGWj/18/